# How to login into salesforce with single sign on

Tags: single-sign-on

My requirement is I have to login into salesforce automatically when I have already logged into the client system by using single sign on settings. By doing some R&D I came to know its easy to do single sign on for facebook,google,linkedin etc if we have a appid and a appsecret. Is their such a solution for logining in with my client details. Any suggestions on this please.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a solution to login using your system login? Have a look at the SSO implementation guide. http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_single_sign_on.pdf

Comment: I have seen that resource. Its too long to read :( .

Comment: If you do not wish to read the guide, take a look into [Set Up Single Sign-On](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/identity_login/identity_login_sso) Trailhead.